# How to retrieve form entry for use as default value?

Tags: 6, forms, database

I'm building a form in a custom module, and I'd like to have that form show as it's default value the value that had been saved to the DB during the previous edit, but I have no idea how to do it.

Here is an example of one of my fields:

```
$form['savings_ages']['savings_age21'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('21'),
'#size' => 10,
'#maxlength' => 10,
'#default_value' => $whatgoeshere?,
);
```

My form is the basis for a calculator, so I've got over 80 fields and only ever expect to have 1 row's worth of information in my table.

I have no idea how to pull that out, so any guidance would be welcome. PLease let me know if I need to provide more detail.

EDIT:
I'm still stuck on this, my normal query works when I test in the sql window of PHPmyadmin:

```
SELECT `factors_age21` FROM `savingfactors` WHERE 1 limit 1
```

but I can't seem to convert it to the correct format to work with db_query function and echo it out as the default value of my form field. PLus I'll still have to make this query 44 times (I have 44 columns) so if there is a more efficient way, I'd appreciate it.

Second Edit:
I'm starting to get a partial result, but it's still wrong.

```
$sql = "SELECT factors_age21 FROM {savingfactors} WHERE factors_age21 LIMIT 1";
$res = db_query($sql);
$item = db_fetch_object($res);

//later
$form['savings_factors']['factors_age21'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('21'),
'#size' => 10,
'#maxlength' => 10,
'#default_value' => print $item,
);
```

It IS producing a result, but it's showing me the number "1", when my correct value is "14"
any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Stephanie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$form['savings_ages']['savings_age21'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('21'),
'#size' => 10,
'#maxlength' => 10,
'#default_value' => $whatgoeshere?,
);
```

I guess `$form['savings_ages']` is a fieldset. If so, then you can use the following code to get the default value that was saved in database during previous edit.

**Explanation**

When you save a form, a variable gets created with the id that you use to create form element. In your case `variable_get('savings_age21', '')` will fetch the previously saved value.

Documentation [variable_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/6)

**Edit**

```
$form['savings_ages']['savings_age21'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('21'),
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#default_value' => variable_get('savings_age21', ''),
);

return system_settings_form($form);
```

Sorry, I forgot about [system_settings_form($form)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7), this way when you save the form a variable with id of form element will get created, later you can retrieve it using `variable_get()`.

If you do not wish to use `system_settings_form($form)`, then you can use [variable_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) to save a variable with any name. You have to do this `variable_set()` inside the submit handler of the form. Later while displaying the form, use the same logic `variable_get()` to retrieve the variable.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the documentation that says that "a variable gets created" somehow automatically? I can't seem to recall anything to that effect.

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't work. I also think that a variable is not automatically created. Thank you for replying!

Comment: With the `system_settings_form()` call this should work. However, depending on Stephanie's module and its purpose, using variables might not be the way to go.

Comment: This is what I'musing, however since I'm using fieldsets, the call to the variable isn't '#default_value' => variable_get('savings_age21', ''),

the variables are being storred as an array (which is great), but I don't know how to ping the array to fill in the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
// Query for default value
global $user;
$savings_age21 = db_query("SELECT savings_age21 FROM {my_table} WHERE uid = :uid", array(':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchField();

$form['savings_ages']['savings_age21'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('21'),
  '#size' => 10,
  '#maxlength' => 10,
  '#default_value' => $savings_age21,
);
```

Or else you could load the row, assuming one row per user:

```
global $user;
$record = db_query("SELECT * FROM {my_table} WHERE uid = :uid LIMIT 1", array(':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchObject();
// later on ...
$form['savings_ages']['savings_age21'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('21'),
  '#size' => 10,
  '#maxlength' => 10,
  '#default_value' => $record->savings_age21,
);
```

Comment: your suggestion does make sense, however I'm not savings any user information to my table.
My DB has 44 columns with one row of information, ideally that single row would only ever have the most up to date set of entries. (I'm not sure thats the most efficient way to set up a DB, but thats a different post). I have 44 ages 21 - 65 with one column for an ID (not user id). does your suggestion still work? need changes? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Yes, just query the default values from your db table and can use that

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not getting it. this is what I have now:
$record = db_result(db_query('SELECT savings_age21 FROM {savingrecommendation} WHERE id = 1'));

//later
$form['savings_ages']['savings_age21'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('21'),
   '#size' => 10,
   '#maxlength' => 10,
   '#default_value' => $record->factors_age21,
   );

no results are being returned, if you have any other suggestions I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: With db_result the value will be in $record

Comment: how do I get it to show? Right now it doesn't. (I'm in D6)

Comment: Did you try: '#default_value' => $record,

Comment: yes, may attempts have produces the value of  "1" so I know it's reaching the DB and finds the answer to be "Ture" but it's not returning the correct value which is "15.00"

Comment: latest attempt was - $factors_age21 = db_result(db_query("SELECT factors_age21 FROM {savingfactors} WHERE 1 limit 1"));

No results (yes, the DB is different)